# Multiple timestamps in same google sheet across multiple tabs

Tags: google-sheets, tabs, timestamp

Hi I'm trying to have my spreadsheet include multiple timestamps across different tabs in this spreadsheet. Whenever data is edited in Column J, I want a timestamp to immediately populate in Column K. I have 4 sheets within the 1 Google Sheet, and I need all of them to have this automated timestamp running independently. Thanks for any help. I've tried looking to other posts, but have a difficult time modifying code from other people's docs to work for my own.

I was using the following script function to get this timestamp. It worked fine when I only had one tab to the google sheet. But now that I have multiple tabs it only updates one sheet. Trying to figure out how to get it to do the same thing across the whole doc.

```
    function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "EST";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "PM Status ";
  var timeStampColName = "Date Update";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Walt'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.  Setup an onEdit() trigger. I tested it.  It works. It currently works on all of the sheets in the spreadsheet but it's easy to limit it to specific sheets.  You could put all the required sheets into an array like `var wantedSheets=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3','Sheet4'];` and do  `wantedSheets.indexOf()` to find out if the current sheet is in or out.

```
function onTimeStampEdit(e) 
{
    var ss=e.source;
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rg=e.range;
    var row=rg.getRow();
    var col=rg.getColumn();
    if(col==9 || col==10)
    {
      sh.getRange(row,11).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

You can use this to setup an installable trigger.  Just add the SpreadsheetId.

```
function installOnEditTrigger()
{
  setupTrigger('onTimeStampEdit','SpreadsheetId');
}

function setupTrigger(funcName,SpreadsheetId)
{
  if(!isTrigger(funcName))
  {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcName).forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetId).onEdit().create();
  }
}

function isTrigger(funcName)
{
  var r=false;
  if(funcName)
  {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers=[];
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++)
    {
      allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
    }
    if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1)
    {
      r=true;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: I've replaced var ss=e.source; with ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    but now it's giving me an error cannot read property range

Comment: Here is a link to the sheet with editing permissions. Thanks. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DE_nd_viCCBYhTyeh92oNc5EOW2YfH5ZLuysfSCjjvM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can't run these functions in manual mode, they need to run from the trigger.

Comment: The problem is that I also had e.range in there and those both require the an event object be there which means you have to run them from a trigger.  I put the code up there for you inaddition to some extra stuff for installing an on edit trigger.